# UICollectionCellView delegate not being fired

Tags: ios, swift

A UICollectionView I have created doesn't want to fire a custom cell delegate.

The cells are displaying, and the test button accepts presses.

I have debugged the code and the cell.delegate is being assigned self.

I have researched this on google and I have come up with nothing. I think my code is ok but I must be missing something?

I would really appreciate any help.

```
//HomeControllerDelegateTesting.swift

import UIKit

class HomeControllerDelegateTesting: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, PostCellOptionsDelegate {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: self.createLayout())
        self.collectionView.register(PostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: PostCell.reuseIdentifier)
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self

    }

    private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                             heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)

        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
                                               heightDimension: .estimated(300))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize,
                                                         subitems: [item])
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)

        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
        return layout
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PostCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? PostCell else { fatalError("Cannot create cell") }

        cell.postTextLabel.text = "Test"
        cell.delegate = self
        //Test to eliminiate the button accepts events
        //cell.optionsButtons.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    @objc func handlePostOptions(cell: PostCell) {
        print("123")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
}
```

```
//  PostCell.swift


import UIKit

protocol PostCellOptionsDelegate: class {
    func handlePostOptions(cell: PostCell)
}


class PostCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "list-cell-reuse-identifier"

    var delegate: PostCellOptionsDelegate?

    let usernameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Username"
        label.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    let postImageView: UIImageView = {
        let control = UIImageView()
        control.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        control.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        control.clipsToBounds = true
        return control
    }()

    let postTextLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Post text spanning multiple lines"
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()


//    private let optionsButtons: UIButton = {
//        let control = UIButton.systemButton(with: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "post_options"), target: self, action: #selector(handleOptions))
//        control.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        return control
//    }()

    let optionsButtons: UIButton = {
        let control = UIButton(type: .system)
        control.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
        control.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOptions), for: .touchUpInside)
        control.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return control
    }()

    @objc fileprivate func handleOptions() {
        print("Handle options button")
        delegate?.handlePostOptions(cell: self)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupComponents()

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setupComponents() {

        self.optionsButtons.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        let labelStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [optionsButtons])
        labelStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        labelStack.axis = .horizontal
        labelStack.alignment = .fill
        labelStack.distribution = .fill
        labelStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        labelStack.layoutMargins.left = 16
        labelStack.layoutMargins.right = 16
        labelStack.layoutMargins.top = 16
        labelStack.layoutMargins.bottom = 16

        let postTextLabelStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [postTextLabel])

        postTextLabelStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        postTextLabelStack.axis = .vertical
        postTextLabelStack.alignment = .fill
        postTextLabelStack.distribution = .fill
        postTextLabelStack.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        postTextLabelStack.layoutMargins.left = 16
        postTextLabelStack.layoutMargins.right = 16
        postTextLabelStack.layoutMargins.top = 16
        postTextLabelStack.layoutMargins.bottom = 16

        let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [labelStack, postImageView, postTextLabelStack])
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .vertical
        stack.alignment = .fill
        stack.distribution = .fill
        stack.backgroundColor = .blue

        self.addSubview(stack)

        //postImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: postImageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

        stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when the `optionsButtons` is created the `self` is still not initialized. Hence you need to make the button `lazy var` so that it could be loaded lazily when the `optionsButtons` is called and the `UICollectionViewCell` is initialized. Adding the target before `self` is initialized doesn't work.

To fix your issue, modify your `optionsButtons` declaration to `lazy var`, like this:

```swift
lazy var optionsButtons: UIButton = {
```

OR

Add the target after the UICollectionViewCell is initialized, like this:

```swift
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    optionsButtons.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleOptions), for: .touchUpInside)
    setupComponents()
}
```

Comment: Hi Frankenstein, do you mind if I ask you something? In my code I tested the button to ensure it worked by adding addTarget..., which is much clearer than a delegate.  I know protocols are used all over iOS but is there a reason I should use a protocol over addTarget directly in the cellForItem? Personally I did feel uncomfortable adding addTarget, but I can't really explain why, it felt very "heavy" if that makes any sense at all? Whereas a delegate felt a bit lighter, I was more comfortable doing it that way (even thought addTarget us much easier to implement and understand)? Any thoughts?

Comment: You're right to feel target are a bit heavy because they hold a one to many type of relationship and delegate hold a one to one. Means you can add new targets and both would work ie., don't get replaced, while in the case of delegates the newer delegate replaces the old one. Try adding more targets with more selectors.

Answer (score 2):

Change your button declaration to this:

```
// make this a lazy var
lazy var optionsButtons: UIButton = {
    let control = UIButton(type: .system)
    control.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
    // add self. to the selector
    control.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleOptions), for: .touchUpInside)
    control.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return control
}()
```

Comment: HI DonMag, thank you for responding, this is great thank you.  Apologies for not accepting this as the answer, Frankenstein below just gave a bit more explanation around why the issue exists and how to resolve it.  But thank you so much for responding.